# How to create git directory in desktop folder

Tags: git

I'm curious about how to create git directory in desktop folder.

I just installed git and typed `git init`, and `.git` directory was made in documents folder.

Can I make git directories in desktop folder?

Comment: This question doesn't really give us enough information to help you: If you run `git init` it will initialize a new git repository in whatever directory you're in: If that didn't happen for you we would need to know what operating system you`re using and some details about exactly what you did and how you're seeing the problem.

Comment: The answer is, "Yes, but why would you want to do this?"  So long as you run `git init`, it'll create the repo where you tell it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very short and still detailed explanation can be found [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-init)

#### git init

> The git init command creates a new Git repository.
>   It can be used to convert an **existing**, unversioned project to a Git repository or initialize a new empty repository.
>
> Most of the other Git commands are not available outside of an initialized repository, so this is usually the first command you’ll run in a new project.
>
> Executing git init creates a `.git` subdirectory in the project root, which contains all of the necessary metadata for the repo.
>
> Aside from the `.git` directory, an existing project remains unaltered (unlike SVN, Git doesn't require a .git folder in every subdirectory).

#### Usage

**git init**

> Transform the current directory into a Git repository. This adds a .git folder to the current directory and makes it possible to start recording revisions of the project.

```
git init <directory>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a new git repo folder anywhere you want: you need to add the name of that folder to your [`git init`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) command:

```
cd c:\users\<yourname>\Desktop
git init newrepo
```

That will create the folder `newrepo` (in `Desktop` in this case)

```
c:\users\<yourname>\Desktop\newrepo\.git
```

It is important to create a new subfolder under `Desktop/`, or git would consider the entire `Desktop/` as a git repo (with its .git in it)